# apache vhost _default_ vs. localhost issue

Tags: apache, vhosts

Don't know how to better describe that for the title. The problem is:

I use vhosts extensively for my work, but occasionally I just slap some files into a localhost/mysite

When I use a vhost (i.e., mysite.local), I can set my first vhost the way it comes "out of the box" and then put the mysite.local vhost block:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
   DocumentRoot C:/UniServer/www
   ServerName localhost
   ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName mysite.local
DocumentRoot "C:/UniServer/www/mysite/public_html/"
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

But if I want to use localhost/mysite, I have to change it to:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/UniServer/www
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Which is a pain, obviously, as it includes an apache restart.

my httpd.conf is set to:

ServerName localhost

.htaccess doesn't seem to be what is affecting it. Would really appreciate it if someone could give me a lead on this!

EDIT: should have mentioned, when I want to use mysite.local, I CANNOT use:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
```

I MUST use:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
```

So it is "broken" in both directions

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Well, egg on my face - sort of

```
<VirtualHost localhost>  for localhost/mysite
```

and

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1> for mysite.local
```

WORKS, with or without a port, AS LONG AS THEY MATCH (both :80 or both nothing)

BUT

```
<VirtualHost _default_>  for localhost/mysite
```

simply does not work, no way, no how - it is only good for mysite.local

This is with hosts file:
    127.0.0.1   localhost
    127.0.0.1   mysite.local

Would be interested if anyone can explain why "*default*" is behaving that way

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're doing this on windows. Take out the SetEnv at the bottom of your mysite.local VHost and you'll need to check 2 things:

Make sure that your hosts file or local DNS has an entry for mysite.local pointing to 127.0.0.1. The hosts file on windows is in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

If that doesn't make it work, make sure you're set to named virtual hosts, something like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

or

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
```

Comment: Thanks - SetEnv has nothing to do with it (although I double-checked to be sure)

Hosts file is fine - sorry I forgot to mention

I've tried with & without NameVirtualHost *:80, but no luck. I'll experiment with it a little more

Comment: Oh, just noticed that your VirtualHost lines don't match. Add the :80 to the second one. Should be <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>

Comment: I appreciate you're trying to help, but this is really not a syntax error..things you are suggesting have no relation to the problem

Please look more closely at the question